# file created through 'truncate -s' can not get expected size

Tags: linux, truncate

I create a file using `truncate -s 1024M a.test`.
I was expecting a file size of `a.test` to be `1024M`, but not getting correct size somehow.

Below is my code.

```
$du -sh a.test
4.0K    a.test
```

When using `ls -l a.test`, it is ok:

```
$ ll a.test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 1073741824 Jul 12 17:26 a.test
```

Can some one help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

du tells you how much actual disk space you use. Since your file does not have any data in it, the OS will store it as a sparse file, so actual disk usage is much smaller than the size of the file. If you check it with "du --apparent-size -sh a.test", then that will report what you expected.